# Making Grid Smaller Even With ScrollBarVisibility Set To Auto WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, scrollbar

I have a grid that is put inside a ScrollBarViewer with horizontal and vertical ScrollBarVisibility set to auto. The grid has some content that has minimal width and height, so if the size of the window is not enough to fit the minimal width and height, I resize the grid and scroll bars appear. This is the desired behaviour. However, if the window is made smaller, the grid and its contents stay the same. I want to achieve that when the window is made smaller, the grid along with the content is made smaller as long as the minimal width and height are not reached. 
The code is as follows:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="300">

    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Background="White">


            <Grid Name="mouseEventGrid" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid Name="chartGrid" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=AxisPointConnections}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```